# How to more elegantly append an audio file to itself when using FFmpeg than the process I have come up with?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

It seems like the macOS QuickTime player app does not support a song playing for curtain number loops

My idea is to append a audio to itself for the curtain numbers.

Here is code:

```
// loop 3 times
ffmpeg -i "concat:nobody.mp3|nobody.mp3|nobody.mp3" -acodec copy out.mp3
```

It works.

But how to append an audio file to itself in a more elegant way than my code handles it now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adapted from [Repeat/loop with ffmpeg?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12905/repeat-loop-input-video-with-ffmpeg)

## concat demuxer

Use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat).

1. Make `input.txt`:

   ```
   file 'nobody.mp3'
   file 'nobody.mp3'
   file 'nobody.mp3'
   ```
2. Concatenate:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mp3
   ```

- It will be more reliable than the concat protocol.
- Useful if you want to add various files (but they must have same attributes).
- In Linux you can automatically make `input.txt`. See "For Linux users" section in [Repeat/loop with ffmpeg?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12905/repeat-loop-input-video-with-ffmpeg)

## -stream_loop

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop 2 -i nobody.mp3 -c copy output.mp3
```

`-stream_loop 2` will play once, then loop twice, so `nobody.mp3` will play 3x. Setting `-1` is infinite loop.

Comment: Quicker: `ffmpeg -stream_loop 2 -i nobody.mp3 -c copy output.mp3`

Comment: @Gyan That should be a new answer. Definitely good advice but it’s buried here in a comment left for another answer.